# How do I calculate checkboxlist values?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

As part of our ongoing survey questionaire design, the code below is used to determine total number of questions for a survey, how many are correct and percentage of correct answers.

The one issue I am having problem with is how to calculate checkboxlist values.

The survey comes in form of radio buttons and checkboxlist values.

With radio button choices, only 1 choice is selected.

But for checkboxlist, there could be more than 1 values.

This makes it difficult to calculate checkboxlist values.

My thinking is to calculate checkbox values the following way:

```
-- plus 1 for each correct answer
-- minus 1 for each wrong answer
-- total from that then divided by the number of correct answers to the question
```

I just don't know how to go about coding it.

Below is the code that does pretty much everything listed above except the checkboxlist values.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
SELECT question, choice, CorrectAnswer, TotalAnswers, CorrectAnswers, 
                                (CorrectAnswers * 100) / TotalAnswers AS totalPercent, 
                                convert(varchar, (CorrectAnswers * 100) / TotalAnswers ) + '%' AS totalPercentStr
                                FROM (
                                     SELECT sq.questionid, sq.question, sc.choice, sq.CorrectAnswer, 
                                       COUNT(sq.questionId) OVER (PARTITION BY sq.SurveyId) AS TotalAnswers, 
                                       COUNT(CASE WHEN sa.choiceid IS NOT NULL AND sc.choice = sq.CorrectAnswer THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY sq.SurveyId) AS CorrectAnswers
                                     FROM Survey s
                                     INNER JOIN SurveyQuestions AS sq ON s.surveyId = sq.SurveyId
                                     INNER JOIN SurveyChoices   AS sc ON sq.questionId = sc.questionId
                                     LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers    AS sa ON sc.choiceId = sa.choiceId AND sa.username = @UserName
                                     WHERE s.surveyId = @SurveyId
                                     AND (sa.username IS NOT NULL
                                     OR
                                         (sa.username IS NULL AND sc.choice = sq.CorrectAnswer))
                                    ) AS derived
                                ORDER BY questionId;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Survey](
>   [SurveyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
>   [Description] [varchar](max) NULL
>
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyQuestions](
>   [QuestionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [SurveyID] [int] NULL,
>   [Question] [varchar](255) NULL,
>   [AnswerType] [char](1) NULL,
>   [CorrectAnswer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
>   [QuestionOrder] [int] NULL
>
>
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyChoices](
>   [ChoiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
>   [Choice] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
>
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyAnswers](
>   [AnswerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
>   [ChoiceID] [int] NULL,
>   [ChoiceText] [varchar](max) NULL,
>   [UserName] [varchar](50) NULL
> ```

Comment: Can you post the table structures?

Comment: @mr.Reband, I have updated the question above with table structures. Thanks for your response.

For some reason, the tables are bunched up together.

Comment: In the case of a checkboxlist, How can `CorrectAnswer` store multiple responses?  It seems like there should be an additional table, called `CorrectAnswers` or something, with a structure similar to `SurveyAnswers`.

Comment: @mr.Reband, ok what kind of values should it have?

In other words, when a user clicks the Submit button to submit a question with correct answers, should it then submit the checkboxlist answers to this table in the form of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 assuming that the first choice is 1, second choice is 2, etc?

And assuming that there is another box that says ALL of the above or None of the above, how should that be stored?

Should this table be pre-populated with answers?

Comment: Can you provide some data.  I got you started at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0bbb5  I was using a AnswerType of 'R' for radiobutton/multiple choice.  Not sure how you have your checkbox answers or questions setup.  If you can provide those questions and 2 users that have some answers that would be great

Comment: @DanP, thank you very much. I don't have any data yet.

I am currently making them up as I go.

For instance, I loaded about 3 dummy Surveys into Survey table like:

World History Survey, Movie Survey, Survey About Microsoft.

Then I would frame up dummy questions along with made up correctAnswer.

Then made up choices and finally submit to SurveyAnswers table.

Comment: @DanP, I forgot to explain that the way I have AnswerType set up, R S for single choice like Radio button choices and M for multiple choices with Checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CorrectAnswers](
  [AnswerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [ChoiceID] [int] NULL,
  [ChoiceText] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

...and pre-populating it with all correct answers.

When a user clicks submit, the table `SurveyAnswers` would get populated.  I assume that's already being done (Otherwise, what would be the point of the `SurveyAnswers` table)

Then, you can do something like this to see the results side by side with the correct answers:

```
SELECT 
    sc.QuestionID, 
    sc.ChoiceID, 
    case when sa.choiceID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end as userSelected, 
    case when ca.choiceID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end as isCorrectAnswer 
from dbo.SurveyChoices sc
LEFT JOIN dbo.SurveyAnswers sa on sc.ChoiceID = sa.choiceID AND sc.QuestionID = sa.QuestionID
LEFT JOIN dbo.CorrectAnswers ca on sc.ChoiceID = ca.choiceID AND sc.QuestionID = ca.QuestionID
```

Note that if your choiceID's are unique then you don't need to include QuestionID in the join condition.

Also, not sure if you need the `ChoiceText` column in the table -- it should probably only be in one table, and my guess is that table would be `SurveyChoices`.

Comment: @mr.Rebrand, I am about to try out your suggested solution. Thanks to both of you. I hope someone can benefit from you guys' generous help.

I guess I am still confused as to how to save checkbox choices.

Do I save by entering A,B and then submit assuming A,B are correct answers?

Comment: On Submit, you should cycle through all of the user's checked items, and insert one record into `SurveyAnswers` per checked item.  There shouldn't be any checks on correctness at that point, as you still want to capture what the user selected regardless of if it is correct.

Comment: @mr.Rebrand, how is that different from surveyChoices table then?

SurveyChoices table is where all possible Answers are loaded. The correct Answer or in case of checkboxes, correct Answers are loaded into SurveyQuestions. User's choices are submitted into SurveyAnswers and then compared to the correct Answer(s) in SurveyQuestions table.

Comment: @Chid Okeh, In my opinion:  `SurveyChoices` should contain all choices.  `SurveyAnswers` should contain all choices that the user selected.  `CorrectAnswers` should contain all correct choices.  There shouldn't even be a `CorrectAnswer` field in `SurveyQuestions`.  The table name suggests that it stores question data, not choice data.  And if you store multiple correct answers in `SurveyQuestions`, you will automatically increment the `QuestionID` field, and it will look like multiple questions (even if the `Question varchar(255)` field stores the same value).

Comment: @mr.Rebrand, Ok I think it makes more sense now. I added the correctAnswer to surveyQuestions because I was looking at some sample survey apps and saw they did exactly the way I did but I believe you are correct the way you are suggesting. Your query though isn't complete. Can you please incorporate yours into mine?

There is still a little problem with the flow - for me anyway.

We load the survey, we load the questions and choices. At what point will correct Answers be loaded into CorrectAnswers table?.

Comment: You have `CorrectAnswer` and `CorrectAnswers` in your select query -- 1 of those is an aggregate (`CorrectAnswers` is a count), and the other is not (`CorrectAnswer` would return multiple rows).  Those two types are incompatible without a `GROUP BY` clause, which doesn't really make sense here.  So I don't know how you expect the resulting data to look.  That's why I posted an example for you to work with, and to alter as needed.

Comment: Ok, I get the query part. I guess I can work with what I have and I do appreciate all your feedbacks.